# Does firestore support queries for medium project?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've a hotel project, let say it a medium-big project, start from registration customer, manage staff, room service, f&b retail, inventory and other hotel's common services in single app.

I've experienced build app from php or python and manage it in own server using ubuntu server. but for next project i want to try something new. i explore firebase and i found firebase product suitable for it.

**Here my Project specification and product plan to use :**

1. angular as frontend framework
2. firestore as database
3. firebase hosting
4. kotlin as android app
5. there are 3rd party (other vendor) can connect with this project through API
6. image/document file save at amazon web service (only path save in firestore)

**Question**

1. is it worth use firestore as database for my project ?
2. maybe anyone can explain advantages and disadvantages use firebase product for my project ?

thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it worth use firestore as database for my project ?

It's just a database. All the available queries should be sufficient for your use case. For example, fetching hotels in a specific city, services offered and most of the features your listed at start of your question. Checkout [perform simple and compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). It should give you a basic understanding of what you can do.

I  don't really like comparing databases (each of them may have their own pros and cons) but Firestore is a completely managed database so you don't have to worry about scaling and managing it. Unless you need some complex queries, projections and aggregation, Firestore could be a good choice.
The [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) are helpful to manage access to your database if you use Firebase Authentication.

Comment: thank for reply. first, just worried if firestore has a limitation, and in the next day i can't use it anymore.. so in my mind i want to make strong knowledge before start development.

Comment: @ltvie I mean you'll have to first plan what features your app needs and then decide that.